# Implement pow(x, n)

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

Why does this function give the wrong answer `-1` rather than the right answer `1` when I try this? `myPow(-1.00000, -2147483648)`

```
double QuickPower(double x, int n) 
{
    if(n==0){
        return 1;
    }

    if(n==1){
        return x;
    }

    if(n>=2){
        int res=n%2;
        double half=QuickPower(x,n/2);
        return res? Half*half*x: half*half;
    }
}

double myPow(double x, int n) {
    return n>=0? QuickPower(x,n):(1/QuickPower(x,-n));
}
```

I just try to run the code below. "Hello World" is printed out. 
Here I did't specify data type but it still pass if statement. Why?
`if (-1 > 2147483648)
{
 cout << "Hello World";
}`

Comment: Have you tried adding some `std::cout << ...` trace so you can see what calculations it's making, and where they diverge from your expectations? Or using a debugger?  Per Mitch's hint - it won't take long find issues.

Comment: `double myPow(double a, double b) { return exp(b * log(a)); }` is way faster and easier (but despite the misleading title, I guess the question is not about that).

Comment: @Amadan: If a < 0, log(a) is undefined (in the real numbers, anyway). But if b is an integer, a^b can still be calculated by repeated multiplication, even when a is negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is due to integer overflow when calculating -n.
On your system (and my local one) `INT_MIN`=-2147483648 and `INT_MAX`=2147483647.

So the problem is that `-(INT_MIN)` is not representable as an integer.
However you can avoid this issue without going to a higher precision integer type:

Since

x<sup>n</sup> = x<sup>n+1</sup> / x  = (1/x) / x<sup>-(n+1)</sup>

we can rewrite the `myPow` as

```
double myPow(double x, int n) {
    return n>=0? QuickPower(x,n):(1/x)/QuickPower(x,-(n+1));
}
```

This function is OK since `-(INT_MIN+1)=INT_MAX`.

It's worth noting that this will have `myPow(0,-k)` return either  +/- Infinity (n=-1) or NaN (n<-1). If you need that case to be consistent then 
a little more work is required. In general the handling of infinite / nan values is tricky for pow (and not "correct" in this, or the original implementation) - it is worth the [man page for the C pow function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pow.3.html) to get all the edge cases.

Comment: why add 1 here ? what does it mean?

Comment: @Martingalemsy because the range of int is from -2147483648 to 2147483647.  The entire binary field can represent 4294967296 numbers. You need to account for the value "0",   0xFFFFFFF = 2147483648 , 0x0000000 = 0 , and 0x7FFFFFF = -2147483647.   Checkout 2's complement for more info

Answer (score 5):

The error is a result of an integer overflow.

Inside `myPow` you negate n when n is negative.

Negating -2147483648 gives 2147483648, which is 1 more than the maximum positive signed 32 bit integer value, which is [2147483647](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2147483647#In_computing). Use a larger integer data type to fix the bug.

Answer (score 3):

Note that [Primitive data type ranges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type) are:

```
short int and int: −32,768 to 32,767 

unsigned short int and unsigned int: 0 to 65,535 

long int: −2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 

unsigned long int: 0 to 4,294,967,295 

long long int: −9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807
```

**Reference:** [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx) and [The GNU C Reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Integer-Types)

As you can see, the minimum value an integer can hold is `−2,147,483,648`, so when you perform `-(−2,147,483,648)` an integer overflow occurred.

So use `long long int` instead of `int` to handle with big signed number.

The following code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double QuickPower(double x, long long int n)
{
    if(n==0){
        return 1;
    }

    if(n==1){
        return x;
    }

    if(n>=2){
        long long int res=n%2;
        double half=QuickPower(x,n/2);
        return res? half*half*x: half*half;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}

double myPow(double x, long long int n) {
    return n>=0? QuickPower(x,n):(1/QuickPower(x,-n));
}

int main () {
    cout << myPow(-1.00000, -2147483648);
}
```

Give me output:

> 1

Comment: The ranges you cite are not standard, or even common.

Comment: From 5.2.4.2.1: "The values given below shall be replaced by constant expressions ... equal **or greater** in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign." You are quoting bare-minimum ranges as maximum ranges.

Comment: You are citing C standard in a C++ question.

Comment: You should use <limits> and std::numeric_limits<T>::max() for C++ NOT limits.h

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Java Solution */

class Solution {

public double myPow(double x, int n) {

if(n == 0) return 1;

if(Math.abs(x-0.0)<0.0000001) return 0.0;

if(Math.abs(x-1.0)<0.0000001) return 1.0;

if(n < 0) x = 1.0/x;

return Power(x, Math.abs(n));

}

double Power(double x, int n){

if(n == 0) return 1;

if(n == 1) return x;

return ((n&0x1) == 1) ? x*Power(x*x, n/2) : Power(x*x, n/2); 
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

C# Simple solution:

```
    class Program
        {
    
            private static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var result = MyPow(-1.00000, -2147483648);
            }
            public static double MyPow(double x, int n)
            {
                return Math.Pow(x, n);
            }
        }
```

after running this code, variable "result"'s value will equal to 1